# Unexpected error when using presentGooglePay from @stripe/stripe-react-native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, google-pay, react-native-google-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Pay in my react-native app. All payment methods like Apple Pay, Credit Card etc. are working great so far. I am using the same backend mechanisms like for other payment methods. When I try to start the GooglePay with the following Code:

```
const { error } = await presentGooglePay({
  clientSecret:paymentIntentSecret
})
```

I can see the native overlay from google pay trys to show up, but also I get the following error:

[image]

Unexpected error ... [OR_BIBED_01]

I didn't find anything for this error

UPDATE
After I changed the following Code to initialize Google Pay, the error message changed: (commented old code, the uncommented code is the change)

```
const { error } = await initGooglePay({
  testEnv:false,
  merchantName:'xxxx',
  countryCode:'DE',

  // cartItems: [{ label: 'xxxxx', amount: _amnt }],
  // country: 'DE',
  // forSetupIntent: false,
  // merchantDisplayName: 'xxxxxx',
  // merchantCountryCode: 'DE',
  // googlePay: true,
  // currency: 'EUR',
  // billingDetails,
  // requiredShippingAddressFields: ['emailAddress'],
  // requiredBillingContactFields: ['name'],
  // isEmailRequired: true,
})
```

Now I can See the GooglePay sheet and when I try to finalize the process, I get [OR_BEBID_07]

I guess the error is related with the fact, that I am deploying to phone from android studio and using the debugging mode. I will try now to upload to android.developer and download the app form test center.

Comment: You're using `testEnv:false` but that will only succeed if you are running the app in production and already got approval from Google (https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay#going-live // https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/request-prod-access) . Maybe try it with `testEnv:true`.

Comment: @karllekko I saw that, thank you! I asked Google now for the approval, if that is the only thing missing, I will answer here and solve the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approval of [google pay](https://pay.google.com/business/console) was required to use it with testEnv:false...